# How to update value in below document in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have below document in MongoDB in which I want to update the 'value' field given the attribute say '64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c5f here.

```
{
  "id": "64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c57",
  "sections": [
    {
      "id": "64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c60",
      "name": {
        "64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c5f": {
          "nodeType": "nodeName",
          "value": "market"
        }
      },
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c62",
          "name": {
            "64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c61": {
              "nodeType": "nodeName",
              "value": "Buy/Sell"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

With the attribute "64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c5f"; here the value of the key "value" is "market". I want to update it. I am only given "64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c5f". How can I do it using Spring Data Mongo or using MongoTemplate?

UPDATE

I was able to write a method to update the JSON document using a recursive method. Improvements in it are welcome.

```
public JsonNode updateValueByKey(JsonNode node, String keyToSearch, Object newValue, ObjectMapper mapper) {
        if (node.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) node;
            JsonNode keyNode = objectNode.get(keyToSearch);
            if (keyNode != null) {
                ObjectNode keyObjectNode = (ObjectNode) keyNode;
                keyObjectNode.put("value",mapper.convertValue(newValue, JsonNode.class));
                return node;
            }
            for (JsonNode child : node) {
                updateValueByKey(child, keyToSearch, newValue, mapper);
            }
        } else if (node.isArray()) {
            for (JsonNode child : node) {
                updateValueByKey(child, keyToSearch, newValue, mapper);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple update operation using the [$](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) identifier operator will suffice:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{
  "sections.name.64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c5f": {
    $exists: true
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "sections.$.name.64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c5f.value": "newValue"
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g7dPC9n4h1J)

Comment: Hey Tom, Thanks for the response. But here I won't be knowing the hierarchy of attributes in the document. I can just update on the basis of "64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c5f" attribute.

Comment: I don't understand, `64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c61` can appear anywhere and in any depth ?

Comment: 64ca0aaa731a2a7284c24c61 will appear only once. if it exists then I have to update the value field for that particular object.